# Opening Program via File in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I made a program in Visual Basic. I published it to see how it works fully rendered. The program lets you make project files which are basically text files disguised in *.rdc format.

You can save info of your project to this file and even open it up in the program through openfiledialog and the program will read the file and load your project you saved. Upon publishing the program, I have it set to where you can open the project file itself and it will launch the program. That works fine.

But how would I go about also loading the project file in the program the same way I have loaded it in the openfiledialog at runtime? I already have the code. It's basically a text streamreader code.

But in the formload event, how would the program detect that it was opened via the project file and then load the file from there?

I hope this makes sense because I do not know how else to explain it.

Comment: `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` The first element is the executable file name, the rest will be the command-line arguments which in your case will be file name(s)

Comment: then inside the brackets i put the streamreader code?

Comment: ugh. how do i reference the file i am opening? it isnt set as a variable nor can it be. and it isnt going to have the same name everytime. because the user can make multiple project files with different names. how does my program reference what file was just opened?

Comment: Err, do you know how arrays work? `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` returns an array of strings. The first element in the array is the name of your executable—you don't care about that, so you can ignore it. The second argument will be the path to the file you're supposed to open. The other arguments would be additional files or arguments, but you probably won't have any of those, so you can ignore them, too. So you want the second element of the array, that's your file name. Pass that string  to your file-open method that you've already written, just as if it was returned by the open dlg.

Comment: but the thing is how do i reference the file? i wont always know what the filename will be or its location. the user can open the text file from anywhere with any name.